# Using of the pronoun 'She' with Objects

Tags: pronouns, british-english

While I was watching 'dinnerladies' yesterday, I noticed that they referred to 'ladder' as (she) in lieu of (it), so I wonder if it was an idiom or accent.

Thanks

- One of the contexts was like this.
  Tony (referring to the ladder): Can you just move it back a foot?
  Stan: No, because it's wedged against the wall back there.
  Tony: Well just lift it up a bit?
  Stan (trying to lift the ladder up): No, she won't.

Comment: It was probably a [fake] accent, as some other (Romantic) European languages have gendered common nouns.

Comment: If it's the third quote [on this WikiQuote page](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dinnerladies#Catering_[2.01]) you're asking about ("_Get your brain around this..._"), then "_she_" is referring to _Glen_, not the ladder.

Comment: Dunno what's usual in British English, but in the US "she" is used for the well-known case of referring to a boat, and often when referring to a motor vehicle as well.   Plus it's often used informally when discussing objects (such as a ladder) being manipulated.  (NB:  I'm NOT using "object" or "manipulated" in a metaphorical sense!)  The "rules" for this latter (or ladder) usage are buried in the heads of workmen, and not really available for detailed examination.